# Matlab - how to set the XScale with log or lan scale?

Tags: matlab

I want to set the axis of a plot in a log scale.

When I'm running the following code:

```
x = (1:100)';
y1 = x;
y2 = x.^2;
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2);
set(ax,'XScale','log');
```

I'm getting:
[image]

The X axis has: 10^0, 10^1, 10^2

1. But I want to see log1, log 10, log 100 and...
2. If I want to set Ln (log e) is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
x = (1:100)';
y1 = x;
y2 = x.^2;
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(x,y1,x,y2);
set(ax,'XScale','log');

set(ax,'XtickLabel', { 'log1' 'log 10', 'log 100' } )
```

Comment: No,
In your answer we still see 10^0, 10^1, 10^2 and I want to see "log" or "ln"

Comment: You asked to see log1, log10 and log100 in your question.  You can put any text you want in the label - i.e. ln(e) etc....

Comment: I think this answer gives what you asked about `log`.